# I to assign a default account to a custom object using Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I am new to salesforce development. I am trying to create a visualforce page which helps to insert a new record into the custom object. Custom object has master-detail relationship with account. I am having issue when assiging a default value to the Account. The account already exists in the accounts table. Here is the Apex class I am trying.

```html
public class RelatedAccount{
    
    public Account parent {get; set;}
public RelatedAccount(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
Transaction__c child = (Transaction__c)controller.getRecord();
     if (child.Account__c != null) { parent = [Select ID,Name FROM Account  WHERE Account.Name = :'1Company Inc.,' LIMIT 1];
 child.Account__c = parent; 
}


}}
```

I am getting the error : ***"Illegal assignment from Account to Id"***

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
child.Account__c = parent.Id
```

In your case you try to put the "whole" account object object into the Lookup field. But this just needs the Id of the parent account.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got rid of the error. But still I am getting a dropdown list. It is not defaulting the account I selected.

Comment: This is the visual force page I am trying to call the value. '<apex:inputField value="{!Transaction__c.Account__c}"/>'

Comment: Now I am getting this exception when I used the debug window to test `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
`

Comment: Can you show me the whole Page please? Or at least the most important parts that are related to the dropdown list? And of course the value is wrong. it should be something like: parent.Account__c since this is the variable you define in the controller

Comment: This is the visualforce page code `<apex:page standardController="Transaction__c" extensions="RelatedAccount"  >``<apex:inputField value="{!Transaction__c.Account__c}"/>`